# Why is objectId from relational query always returning null when I can get the value of other fields?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to get the objectId of a Pointer from a query. Getting the objectId from a Pointer<_User> works, but getting objectId from my custom Pointer doesn't work, though I can access the other fields in Pointer without problem.

Below I comment the different ways I have tried, and what works and doesn't work. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> testQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Sell");
testQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()); // A Pointer<_User> field.
testQuery.include("user");
testQuery.include("book");                                  // A Pointer<Book> field.
testQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> bookListResults, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (ParseObject object : bookListResults) {
                log("objectId: " + object.getObjectId()); // Works

                log("userObjectId: "  + object.getParseObject("user").getObjectId()); // Works

                log("bookObjectId: "  + object.getParseObject("book").getObjectId()); // null


                ParseObject bookObject = object.getParseObject("book");
                log("bookObjectId: "  + bookObject.getObjectId());         // null
                log("bookObjectId2: " + bookObject.getString("objectId")); // null
                log("bookIsbn13: "    + bookObject.getString("isbn13"));   // Works
                log("bookIsbn10: "    + bookObject.getString("isbn10"));   // Works
                log("bookGoogleId: "  + bookObject.getString("googleId")); // Works
            }
        } else {
            CustomToast.showToast(getActivity(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

ps - The objectId field is filled out in the Parse Data Browser.

ps - I'm using Parse-1.4.3 for Android.

**Update:**
- In the above code, `Book` is a full subclass extending ParseObject, and using `ParseObject.registerSubclass(Book.class)` and `@ParseClassName("Book")`.

When I remove the registerSubclass() and annotation, then the objectId works! This is a repeatable error.

I haven't found the reasoning behind this yet. Any further insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you have a reference to the OID is when you first create it and the json returned has the value.

myObj.getObjectId() will return nulls.

see discuss of same topic over in [parse javascript forum](https://parse.com/questions/javascript-get-objectid) where there is a workaround.

AFAIK android SDK has no workaround.

But with android, You can use REST API from android to get the OID.

Rest sample for OID (see 'objectId' at bottom of code):

```
GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ovv"  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: eoj"  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: 9ds" -G --data-urlencode 'limit=2'  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyCls

{
"results":[
{
"createdBy":{
"__type":"Pointer",
"className":"_User",
"objectId":"I2bhDkeA5L"
},
"media1":{},
"media2":{},
"media3":{},
"msg":"hi how are you ",
"createdAt":"2014-03-07T05:32:48.906Z",
"updatedAt":"2014-03-09T00:31:01.498Z",
"objectId":"XPdLazBUzV",   ********
"ACL":{}
},
```

Comment: Thank you, but I believe the objectId should be coming back with every query, as it did with 2 of the 3 ParseObjects in my original question. I have updated the post with further information to help properly get the objectId via ParseQuery using their Android SDK.

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/android-guide-problem  maybe ur problem is async lag as mention in this one.